# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value error Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting the error that i wrote in the title and after looking at all the other stack overflow threads but none of them really explain where the problem comes from.

When I launch the application it instantly crashes and highlights this line in red:

```
let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("HitList", withExtension: "momd")!
```

My main View controller that the app launches to has this code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var subjects = [NSManagedObject]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self,
        forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return subjects.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath
    indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell =
        tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")

        let check = subjects[indexPath.row]

        cell!.textLabel!.text =
            check.valueForKey("name") as? String

        return cell!
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

@IBAction func addName(sender: AnyObject) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Subject", message: "Add a new Subject", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save",
        style: .Default,
        handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in

            let textField = alert.textFields!.first
            self.saveName(textField!.text!)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
    })


    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
        style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    }

    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
        (textField: UITextField) -> Void in
    }
    alert.addAction(saveAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    presentViewController(alert,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)
}
func saveName(name: String) {

    let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext


    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Subjects",
        inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

    let check = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
        insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)


    check.setValue(name, forKey: "name")


    do {
        try managedContext.save()

        subjects.append(check)
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)


    let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext


    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Subjects")


    do {
        let results =
        try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        subjects = results as! [NSManagedObject]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle,forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "ShowAssesment") {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell((sender as? UITableViewCell)!)
        let listVC = segue.destinationViewController as? AssesmentViewController

        let subject = subjects[indexPath!.row]

        listVC?.assesments = ["Death"]
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Thank You, that has worked and i was able to change it, one other problem that i have had is that when i click on a segue it doesn't transfer to the other table view even though i have made a show segue with the id ShowAssesment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to unwrap a value that doesn't exist on the line..

```
let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("HitList", withExtension: "momd")!
```

Locate the file you're trying to obtain and make sure it exists and that it's called HitList.momd. And do this instead...

```
var modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("HitList", withExtension: "momd")
```

So just in case the file doesn't exist your app doesn't crash.

Answer (score 3):

When `let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("HitList", withExtension: "mom")!` is executed, the file HitList is not found and the result is nil. You cannot unwrap nil.

Answer (score 0):

The [`URLForResource`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/URLForResource:withExtension:subdirectory:) method according to Apple:

> Returns the file URL for the resource file identified by the specified name and extension and residing in a given bundle directory.

And returns :

> The file URL for the resource file or `nil` if the file could not be located. This method also returns `nil` if the bundle specified by the `bundlePath` parameter does not exist or is not a readable directory.

You need to check before unwraps it, remember every time you use the `!` operator to unwrap an optional you say to the compiler that the variable always have a value, you can fix it using optional binding like in the following way:

```
if let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("HitList", withExtension: "momd") {
    // do whatever you what with the value 
}
else {
   // the value is nil
}
```

Or instead use the new `guard` statement in Swift 2.0 like in the following way;

```
guard let let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("HitList", withExtension: "momd") else {
   // the value is nil
   return
}
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, that has worked. John Doe's didn't work as it still gave the error message but changing the URLForResource in this case to the name of the xcdatamodeld name.